# Rails link_to with same page anchor and class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to use rails link_to to produce

```
<a href="/#about" class="leftnav__link">about</a>
```

I have tried

```
<%= link_to "about", anchor: "about", class: "leftnav__link" %>
```

which results in

```
<a href="/?class=leftnav__link#about">about</a>
```

The anchor surprisingly works but the class name is not placed correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is mixing the `options` and `html_options` arguments ([docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)).
If you're trying to link to the an about element on the page at `/`, you'd need something like this:

```rb
<%= link_to "about", root_path(anchor: 'about'), class: "leftnav__link" %>
```

If you're trying to link to the about element on the current page (just to scroll to it), you'd do something like:

```rb
<%= link_to "about", '#about', class: "leftnav__link" %>
```

or

```rb
<%= link_to "about", { anchor: 'about' }, class: "leftnav__link" %>
```